# Keep Picturebox Image While Painting on top of it

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, paint

In my form, I have a picturebox. I wanted to be able to draw arrows on top of an image. I managed to get halfway there. On the Form load event, I assign an image to the picturebox. I'm able to create arrows with the code below. The problem is every time I create the arrow the picture I assigned on my form load event gets erased. Why does my image get erased? How do I maintain my image that I assigned on form load while drawing arrows on top of it?

```
    private bool isMoving = false;
    private Point mouseDownPosition = Point.Empty;
    private Point mouseMovePosition = Point.Empty;
    private List<Tuple<Point, Point>> lines = new List<Tuple<Point, Point>>();
    Pen _Pen;

    private void Test_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.background;          
    }

    private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {

        if (isMoving)
        {
            if (pictureBox1.Image == null)
            {
                Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);
                using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
                {
                    g.Clear(Color.White);
                }
                pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
            }

            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(pictureBox1.Image))
            {
                g.Clear(pictureBox1.BackColor);

                AdjustableArrowCap bigArrow = new AdjustableArrowCap(5, 5);
                _Pen = new Pen(Color.IndianRed, 3);
                _Pen.CustomEndCap = bigArrow;
                g.DrawLine(_Pen, mouseDownPosition, mouseMovePosition);
                _Pen.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }



    private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        isMoving = true;
        mouseDownPosition = e.Location;
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (isMoving)
        {
            mouseMovePosition = e.Location;
            pictureBox1.Invalidate();
        }
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (isMoving)
        {
            lines.Add(Tuple.Create(mouseDownPosition, mouseMovePosition));
        }
        isMoving = false;
    }
```

I think the problem is with this line here `g.Clear(pictureBox1.BackColor);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, problem is with this line here `g.Clear(pictureBox1.BackColor);` You erase entire the control area before you draw the line.

You should draw to `e.Graphics` directly:

```
private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (isMoving)
    {
        if (pictureBox1.Image == null) e.Graphics.Clear(Color.White);

        // Add this line for high quality drawing:
        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;

        AdjustableArrowCap bigArrow = new AdjustableArrowCap(5, 5);
        _Pen = new Pen(Color.IndianRed, 3);
        _Pen.CustomEndCap = bigArrow;
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(_Pen, mouseDownPosition, mouseMovePosition);
        _Pen.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Sakura, this worked. Thank you! This preserves the background image and draws arrows on it, but do you know why the picturebox image doesn't equal the drawn arrow above the background picture? The way I tested this was i put another picturebox control in my form and just wrote `picturebox2.image = picturebox1.image` and it only displayed my background image.

Comment: Change ` if (pictureBox1.Image == null)` to ` if ((sender as PictureBox).Image == null)`. Anyway, I'm not clearly understand your comment. If possible, edit your question with new code and I will see if I can help

Comment: Hi Sakura, I asked the question here in more detail with tests I ran. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46592322/paint-drawline-image-into-picturebox-image

Comment: @taji01 ok I see the problem. I will post the solution in few minutes.